# Xamarin Forms C# Async function implementation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

If I run this code, will `editButton` wait to become enabled until my (asynchronous) `getMachines()` function has finished running? If not, how do I create this functionality?

```
 editButton.isEnabled = false;
 loadedMachines = await azureService.GetMachines();
 editButton.isEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes edit button will wait for upper functionality to finish first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, await keyword will make your thread wait for the response.

Don't forget to add async keywork on your method and to return a Task<> in GetMachines()